# MacBook battery won't charge but powers on either battery or direct power source

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management, magsafe

My MacBook won't charge. When I plug the magsafe adapter it doesn't light up (no amber nor green). I tried using a friend's charger to check if the adapter is at fault but the result is the same. So I removed the battery then magsafe lights up and powers the computer. I check the battery cycle and it is normal with 515 count. While computer is turned on and while the magsafe adaptor is plugged to the power supply I put the battery back, then it started charging again. I unplugged the magsafe adapter to check if it is finally working and it went back to not charging and no green or amber light, but the MacBook is running from the battery. So I  bought a new battery for replacement but I still have the same issue.

Has anyone experienced this or any insight to what might be the problem?

Is this a battery problem or charger issue?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Also please have a look at other magsafe/battery related questions on this site, the issue might have come up before.

Comment: Edited the post